# Having trouble extending class (Dont understand whats wrong and dont understand other complex explanations on this site.)

Tags: java

Basically the line `super(int health, int strength, int speed, int type);` keeps giving me an error that says...

> .class expected.

Here is the code:

```
public class Pokemon {
    private int health;
    private int strength;
    private int speed;
    private int type;

    public Pokemon(int health, int strength, int speed, int type) {
      assert health >= 0;
      assert health <= 300;
      assert strength >= 1;
      assert strength <= 3;
      assert speed >= 1;
      assert speed <= 300;
      assert type >= 1;
      assert type <= 3;

      this.health = health;
      this.strength = strength;
      this.speed = speed;
      this.type = type; 
    }
}

public class PokemonTester extends Pokemon {
    PokemonTester() {
       super(int health, int strength, int speed, int type);
    }
    {
       Pokemon charizard = new Pokemon(100,2,50,1);
       Pokemon blastoise = new Pokemon(150,2,150,1);
       Pokemon venusaur = new Pokemon(300,2,100,1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove type of parameters and add parameters to class constructor.

```
PokemonTester(int health, int strength, int speed, int type) {
   super(health, strength, speed, type);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When calling the constructor of the `super` class, you'll have to actually pass values to it. This can be done by including the parameters from your the super class in your constructor:

```
PokemonTester(int health, int strength, int speed, int type) {
   super(health, strength, speed, type);
}
```

Which is probably what you intended to do.

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong

```
super(int health, int strength, int speed, int type);
```

U should pass values here not to "declare them" so for example

```
super(200,50,50,1);
```

would compile just fine.
`super` here means that you are invoking constructor of superclass (class that your current class is extending from)
In your case this would be a call to a constructor of `Pokemon` class

Normally you would like to pass some arguments from current constructor to a underlying, nondefault (with some arguments) constructor of superclass